# Comparator Data Structure ordering - how to maintain insertion order whilst ordered on another field?

Tags: java, data-structures, comparator

I have a data structure which takes an optional `Comparator` to customise ordering (in this case it is a `TreeSet` but really it doesn't matter, I can swap out for a `PriorityQueue` without breaking my code). At present, it is ordered by a field `price` on the object which the structure is storing.

When 2 objects have the same price, I want `timestamp` to be the tie-breaker, timestamp being `System.CurrentTime`. To specify this in the comparator I have to use:

`if (Object1.getPrice == Object2.getPrice && Object1.Timestamp > Object2.Timestamp) return 1`

The problem is that this breaks the equals case when I do `TreeSet.floor()` or `TreeSet.ceiling()` - the method no longer recognises that 2 objects are of equal price but will still recognise if the price is higher/lower. How do I mitigate this?

Comment: There is no poll() method in TreeSet. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry I meant either pollfirst or polllast

Comment: pollFirst returns the first element of the set. How is equality relevant? Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet apologies, it's been a very long day :) I mean floor/ceiling methods

Comment: Well, pass an Object with Long.MAX_VALUE as the timestamp when calling floor(), and Long.MIN_VALUE as the timestamp when calling ceiling

Comment: how would that help? I'm talking about how it breaks the equivalence formula, i.e. the struct no longer recognises that 2 objects are the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Comparator` you decide what is the order of the set (actually as well their "uniqueness"!).
So **you** have to decide if the objects are equal:

- if the Price is the same
- if the Price and Timestamp is the same

maybe using different data-strucure for this different usages would be an option or a different that could cover both. Depending on the other requirements and boundaries of your code.

---

Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their **natural ordering, or by a Comparator** provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So you provide the Comparator.

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface**. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a **TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method**, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

So if there is already a `equals` object in the Set (consulting the comparator) it want be added again **as this would be placed at the very same position in the Set according to the order** (if you don't like that don't use a Set). They should be implemented consistent (even tough it is not forced by the compiler). So instead of using direct `equals` it used the comparator.
Internally the comparator could use the `equals` operator of the objects (inside the if statement like `if(obj1.equals(obj2)){return 0;}`).
But how to implement the `equals` - internally it would rely on some property comparison (like you do now in the comparator).
If you don't like that for your data structure maybe don't use a (Tree)Set.
Depending on the needs a Map or a List might be fine.
Choosing the right Collection: 
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65

---

For the difference between `==` and  `equals`:

- `==` is comparing the references, lets say the pointer to the container, if true it is the same instance.
- `equals` is comparing the object, lets say the content of the object container, if true it holds same value(s) (in its properties)

But out there are probably millions of exhausting articles on that.
*Note:* `equals` of an Object should be implemented consistent with the hashCode() method. And for a (Tree)Set the comparator should be implemented consistent with `equals` (maybe use something like `if(obj1.equals(obj2)){return 0;}`). Furthermore, other `Set` implementations use the hasCode() for that.

Comment: what is this `compactor`? can't find any javadocs on it. If you mean `Comparator`, then yes, defining the 'uniqueness' as well seems bizarre to me...I can specify the order, but why does the ordering make me also specify the 'uniqueness'? To me it's similar to the problem `.equals` vs `==`

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine: ha it is a comparator - auto correction. sorry for that. Actually you provide the comparator just for that purpose - ordering it and pollFirst/Last() is polling the first/last depending on the ordering determined by your comparator. Why/What si wanted if ordering based on Price & Time but than polling _what_ as first/last? Uniqueness as the Set has already an Item if it is the same (in order).

Comment: sorry edited my comment - it is to do with uniqueness actually, I am confused why the struct looks at comparator to find uniqueness/equivalence of objects, rather than the `.equals` method

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine: First the Set only contains unique entries - second the TreeSet is using the comparator if you provide it, for that reason - thats its implementation. comparator compares objects, like equals does. Sure they could be different but TreeSet uses what is provided (comparator in that case, otherwise natural ordering). (and according to the JavaDoc they have to be consistent)